# How to compute the indefinite integral of $1/(1+x^2)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

The manipulation of logarithms in $(*)$ doesn't hold over the complex numbers. I'm not deleting it, as the answers I got, and the rest of my post make no sense without it, but I also don't want to confuse anyone who may also be new to complex logarithms.

I know the integral upto addition of a constant is $\tan^{-1}(x).$ And, in fact it's not hard to show. However, I'm curious about the case where you start from $1/(1+x^2),$ and without knowing $d/dx\tan^{-1}(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ solving
$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$

Let us work modulo constants, so we need not write them. Then
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\int\left(\frac{1}{2i(x-i)}-\frac{1}{2i(x+i)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\ln(x-i)-\ln(x+i)\right)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)}{2i}.\text{ }(*)$$
It should be clear now that our result is purely real, as $|(x-i)/(x+i)|=1.$ Moreover, it is clear that 
$$\ln\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)=i\cdot\text{argument}\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right).$$

Now, I know that
$$\frac{x-i}{x+i}=\frac{(x-i)^2}{{x^2+1}}=\frac{x^2-1}{{x^2+1}}-\frac{2xi}{{x^2+1}}.$$

This tells us
$$\tan\left(\text{argument}\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)\right)=-\frac{2x}{x^2-1}.$$
So we can deduce that
$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\right).$$

From here I'm not quite sure how to proceed though. How would one show that modulo constants
$$\tan(x)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-2x}{x^2-1}\right)?$$

I guess it is clear if you differentiate both, but that presumes we already had $\tan^{-1}(x)$ in mind.

Comment: $\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})$

Comment: @zwim As it stands your comment already contains the essential idea. Perhaps promote it to a full answer?

Comment: @zwim Thank you, that's exactly the identity I needed.

Comment: Your analysis is not meaningful. Logarithms of complex numbers cannot be manipulated so easily. In particular it is not true that $log (ab)=log (a)+log(b)$ irrespective of which branch of logarithm you are using.

Comment: @KaveRamaMurthy Okay, any ideas for how to proceed instead? We would have $\ln(a+bi)\equiv\ln|a+bi|+i\tan^{-1}(b/a),$ correct? This would gives us an indefinite integral of $-\tan^{-1}(1/x).$ Well, $\tan(x)=\sin(x)/\cos(x),$ so $-\tan^{-1}(1/x)=-\cot^{-1}(x)?$ Then $\cot(x)=\tan(\pi/2-x)$ gives us our result, right? Alternatively, I suppose we could just stop at $-\cot^{-1}(x),$ it's not the answer I was looking for, but it's simple enough that I would be happy if I found it as the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-2x}{x^2-1}\right)?$$

Let $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-2x}{x^2-1}\right)=\alpha$$

That is $$ \tan \alpha = \frac{2x}{1-x^2} = \frac {2\tan (\alpha /2)}{1-\tan ^2 (\alpha /2)}$$

With $$x= \tan (\alpha /2)$$ we get $$ \tan ^{-1} (x) = \alpha /2$$

Which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Since your are making it an answer, it would be better to make explicit why / there is / or there is not /  a multiple of $\pi$ after the "we get" line, especially when dealing with reciprocal of periodic functions.

Comment: I think you could have pointed how horribly wrong OP's use of logarithms is . This page is very misleading.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I made a mistake there. I'll admit that. I'm not super used to complex logarithms. You don't have to say it is horribly wrong though. That kind of language is discouraging to people studying mathematics. Please be more respectful.

Comment: @Melody Very sorry. I had no intention to discourage you.My intention was to give clear warning to others young students reading this page. By no means was it meant to hurt you.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. I appreciate the response.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see why you would want to give a warning. I put a disclaimer at the beginning of the post about that.

Comment: @Melody I really appreciate what you have done. You are very honest and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $$\frac12\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=\frac12\arctan\left(\frac{x+x}{1-xx}\right)=\frac12\left(\arctan x+\arctan x\right)=\frac12\left(2\arctan x\right)=\arctan x.$$